# How fresh is the coffee provided in hotel rooms?

Tags: ground-coffee

I travel frequently, and sometimes in the morning I want a quick cup of coffee.

The first thing I see is these mini coffee machines in the room.  They sometimes come in generic pouches, but at fancier hotels they'll have brands (doubletree serves branded ones).

How fresh is this kind of coffee?

Answer (score 3):

There is a great variation as to how "fresh" this coffee is. Being pre-ground coffee it was ground a while before you arrived in the hotel; however, it is not any fresher or less fresh than other store bought pre-ground coffee.